# modify a cronjob to make it run every half an hour starting next month

Tags: cron

I have the following cronjob which runs every 30 min, and i want to change it to make it run every half an hour starting from next month(September). I need to change it because it is overriding some changes I am doing

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/iga-chef-client -s 2 >> /var/chef...
```

should it be this way:

0,30 * * 9 *.....

this runs every 30 minutes starting from the month of September, but i am not sure if it is the correct way to put it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your entry will only run during September and will stop running the job on October 1st.  I don't think there is a way to start running it on September 1st and continue running it every day after that without editing cron between 23:30 and 23:59 on August 31.